# Is there a way to transform a JSON Schema definition into a Big Query Schema definition?

Tags: json, google-bigquery, jsonschema

From https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas a Schema Definition File looks like

```
[
  {
    "name": string,
    "type": string,
    "mode": string,
    "fields": [
      {
         object (TableFieldSchema)
      }
    ],
    "description": string,
    "policyTags": {
      "names": [
        string
      ]
    },
    "maxLength": string,
    "precision": string,
    "scale": string,
    "collation": string,
    "defaultValueExpression": string
  },
  {
    "name": string,
    "type": string,
    ...
  }
]
```

Is there any tool/product that can take a https://json-schema.org file, and convert it to the form that Big Query prefers?

Comment: Can you share a specific file from the site you mentioned? Read it and its just an overview of the organization.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect a json schema from a file (which is stock into a bucket in the same GCP project for example) with using a external table link to your file. The data from your file will be print into Bigquery. (you can use command line too, i never use it but it exist too )

Example in csv (json is possible too) :
Create or replace external table `projectGCP.DatasetsGCP.TableGCP` OPTIONS ( format = 'CSV', uris = ['gs://nameofmybucket/*pattern_i_want_tobe_detect_inthe_namefile.csv'] )

After doing that, you can go to the table created just before and get Bigquery schema of the table.

Here more information how you can do it (*You can provide the schema inline (on the command line) or you can provide a JSON file containing the schema definition*, it's possible too) : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-table-definition